# dynamic time formatting with flot.tooltip

Tags: jquery, time, tooltip, flot

I'm using the `flot.tooltip` plugin for `flot` and my data is a time-series.  Users can choose the time frame of the data to be graphed (7 different steps from 7 days to 'all data') and flot re-formats the x-axis accordingly - 'Jan 03, Jan 04, etc' if 7 days, 'Jan, Feb, etc' if 1 year, and so on.

The problem is that when using the tooltips, the date is NOT formatted as it's just getting the raw unix timestamp, giving me output like `138887...` in the tooltip.

There is a time format option, but since my dataset can be changed by the user, this option doesn't work.  Is there a way to dynamically format timestamp data with the flot.tooltip plugin?

Current relevant code is as follows:

```
tooltip: true,
tooltipOpts: {
  content: function(label, xval, yval) {
    var section = $("#select-buttons").find('li.selected a')[0].innerHTML;
    switch (section) {
    case "Country":
      return xval + ':\n ' + yval + ' users from ' + label
      break;
    ...
    }
  },
}
```

## solution:

I had to change a few things from the accepted answer, most notably `plot.getXAxes()` > `plot.getAxes().xaxis`.  Also I had to create the plot as a named variable so I could access `plot.getAxes().xaxis` and then call `plot.draw();` at the end - before the initial `$.plot(...)` was just inside of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to apply the formatting yourself.  Something like this in the `content` callback:

```
tooltipOpts: {
    content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem){
        var xAxis = plot.getXAxes();
        var range = (xAxis.max - xAxis.min);

        if (range > 3.15569e10){
          // range is larger than a year, just show year
          return $.plot.formatDate(new Date(xval), '%Y');

        }else if (range > 2.62974e9){
          // range is less than a year, larger than a month, show month names
          return $.plot.formatDate(new Date(xval), '%m');

        }else if (range > 604800000){                                    
          // range is less than a month, larger than a week
          etc...

        }else if (range > 86400000){
          // range is less than a week, larger than a day
          etc...

        }else{
          etc...
        }

    }
},
```

I'm using flots data formatting function from `jquery.flot.time.js`, if is isn't advanced enough for your needs I'd recommend the venerable [moment.js.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: cheers, that worked.  I had to change a few small things, most notably `plot.getXAxes()` > `plot.getAxes().xaxis` but i will include them in my OP in case it helps someone else with this issue. thanks again!